# Changing From Name in MailMessage

Tags: c#, asp.net

I am using C# MailMessage for sending Email, I have an email Address from which email is sent, this will be fix for all emails, I want to change Sender Name,
Below is my code:

```
MailMessage emailmsg = new MailMessage("abc@gmail.com", "toemail@gmail.com");
```

Here it's getting the name which I provided while signing up "abc@gmail.com". How can I change this name? as this name will be different each time.
Is it possible to change Sender's Name?
I have seen the documentation of MailMessage [Here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.net.mail.mailmessage%28v=vs.110%29.aspx),but I am unable to find any property to change the sender's name.

I have tried using mailmessage MailAddress Constructor like this

```
MailMessage emailmsg = new MailMessage();
            emailmsg.To = new MailAddress("toemail@gmail.com");
            emailmsg.From = new MailAddress("abc@gmail.com", "MyName");
```

its giving error

```
Property or indexer MailMessage.To is readonly
```

Comment: Try the constructor overload that accepts two `MailAddress` instances.

Comment: Your error is because the `To`/`From` properties are `readonly` - they need to be passed in at constructor level (see my answer).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use the [overloaded](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/s9d2we92%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) constructor of `MailMessage` which accepts [MailAddress](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.net.mail.mailaddress%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) instances instead of email addresses, this will allow you to create a new mail address with a display name

```
var sender = new MailAddress("toemail@gmail.com", "Sender");
var recipient = new MailAddress("abc@gmail.com", "Recipient");
var msg = new MailMessage(sender, recipient);
```

Comment: its giving exception "Sender signature not defined for From address."

Comment: @SyedSalmanRazaZaidi that sounds like a problem with your mail server, not this code.

Comment: its not wokring for outlook office 365 email MailAddress mailFrom = new MailAddress("sender@xyz.com", "Sender Name"); this takes the user name automatically

Comment: @KumarV that would most likely be an issue with O365 either not allowing, or not configured, to use display names.